# how do I readirect t another path

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have this code and I want to forward to another path when id == 1

```
get("/courses/{id}"){
    val id = call.parameters["id"]?.toInt()
    if (id is Int) {
        if (id == 1)
        // i want redirection to "/courses/top"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `call.respondRedirect`:

```
if (call.parameters["id"]?.toIntOrNull() == 1) {
    call.respondRedirect("/courses/top")
}
```